# How does Google Docs manage to get paste on click to work?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, google-docs

I would like to implement a paste-on-click function, similar to that found in Google Docs.

I can get paste to work when initiated by the user via the context menu, or via a keyboard shortcut (using the onpaste event and friends), but I am unable to work out how to get a paste-on-click style actuation to cause the contents of the system clipboard to get pasted - and, from what I've read, this shouldn't actually be possible!

Does anybody have any clue as to how Google is making this work? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't actually a solution, but more of a workaround. But maybe you'll find it worthy and would suit your needs.

Wouldn't be possible to emulate the key press for [Ctrl]+[V]? It will work on *most* browsers and OSes, but always keep in mind these keys can be changed at OS level anytime.

Any solution more than this kind of workaround may be too cumbersome for your script some times, and there are times when you just don't want to have too many events/listeners.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Victor, though this would only send Ctrl+V (or similar) to the document rather than triggering what is effectively an OS action.

Comment: Look, I stumbled upon a nice article on this topic: http://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/

Comment: Yes, I'm actually asking you to come back and share the results and methods if anything works out ok. I can foresee this issue as one of my own in the near future, so it would be very helpful. TIA.

Comment: Sorry, the click-on-paste is not possible with today's standards, though this is with caveats - it is possible in Chrome if you're willing to create an offline app (which has different sandbox rules), but I was hoping to cast the net wider than this and, in my case, an offline app is not feasible.